# Adding Authorization Policy breaks default/scaffolded Identity returnurl in ASP.NET 6 Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages, .net-6.0

I am encountering an issue where the returnurl is not being formatted correctly after adding an Authorization Policy to my ASP.NET 6 Web App Program.cs.

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Create ASP.NET 6 Web App with Individual Accounts.
2. Create SQL Server Database and update Connection String in appsettings.json.
3. Update-Database to create the default ASP.NET Identity tables.
4. Scaffold all Identity Pages using the default ApplicationDbContext and IdentityUser.

At this point everything works as it should. I am able to register a new user and login.

5. Add Authorization Policy to program.cs to require a user be logged in to access the app.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    });
```

Lauching the app at this point results in being taken to a broken URL:

(on MS Edge)
Hmmm… can't reach this page
It looks like the webpage at https://localhost:7094/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FIdentity%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FIdentity%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FIdentity.......etc

The url endlessly repeats with more '%25F' being added each time it loops.

Adding [AllowAnonymous] to the Login and Register Pages allows me to access them but I am still unable to actually successfully register a new user. After registration, clicking the 'Normally this would be emailed: Click here to confirm your account' link brings me to a similarly broken URL:

https://localhost:7094/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FIdentity%2FAccount%2FConfirmEmail%3FuserId%3Def48b287-bac4-4b21-afbc-f060e1ba859d%26code%3DQ2ZESjhBS2tOazZqZ1IxSWl3NVdudEJhSUhLckxsY2NMZytON1JSaVlPYkRLOE50ako2THFWOXRIZ2UzVFB4VmxFZ0JUYWQ0djg2TXNLcVpyS3c2VndEcUtNdG5DdkNBdzhnak95TUQ4U25nSTltU2cvRzNzMUt5ZHgvNGd6WjhFdnlYUy85RmMzU2g0VHY3WURhOHl0TVJPay8wbGI1b0JFV3hWcEZNYkQ1S2Q5U1VuNEh6ZlZkOEIrOWFEdGxYQVBWR2hIZjVnaENLditwSjJaWUoyMHNWOHp3VzVIanJ4cnh0NEEwUTNHdjZNNlEyRC9ZdUVORmZZOXM3NVZjeWtvcHIrUT09%26returnUrl%3D%252FIdentity%252FAccount%252FLogout

This results in the EmailConfirmed column in the database not being set to True and I am unable to log in as the created user.

Does anyone have any idea what would be causing the url to be formatted this way? The Authorization code above is the only code I added to the project myself, everything else is default/scaffolded.

Comment: `Lauching the app at this point results in being taken to a broken URL:`,can you share the code of Login which returns the url？

Comment: The behavior is reported as a bug [Scaffolded Identity UI pages lack AllowAnonymous attribute](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Scaffolded-Identity-UI-pages-lack-AllowA/10175753)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This helped me.

https://andrewlock.net/setting-global-authorization-policies-using-the-defaultpolicy-and-the-fallbackpolicy-in-aspnet-core-3/

I put the [AllowAnonymous] decoration on:

- AccessDenied.cshtml.cs
- ForgotPasswordModel.cshtml.cs
- ForgotPasswordConfirmation.cshtlm.cs
- Login.cshtml.cs
- Error.cshtml.cs

I think that it would work for you if you add it also too the ConfirmEmailModel.cshtml.cs

I don't need the register pages or 2fa pages.
For now it seems to work if someone knows an better solution I would be happy to hear about it.